# How to use a View in a Fragment inside a TabLayout's tab in Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tablayout

I want to know how to access a view inside a fragment from an activity, knowing that the fragment shows in a tab under TabLayout. When I define for example a TextView1 -which is in fragment- in Activity, no problem with that, but once I need to set an action for TextView1 -like onClickListener- it crashes.

I don't know if I can do it like this directly, or I have to get the fragment first from inside the tab. As I said, trying to do an action directly would make the app crashes, about getting the fragment or the view from inside the tab, I have no clue.
The error I get for that is: **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.edittext.settext(java.lang.charsequence)' on a null object reference**

I just need to know what to add in fragment's java class, or in Activity class or both to make the goal view accessible in Activity.

Comment: It's not a good practice to directly access views of fragment from the activity, but that should not cause a crash. You should post the error log and some of your codes so others can help you

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem, I had a problem because I was thinking about context without realizing it. Now that I know my exact problem, I didn't know how to use the context in a fragment, but I noticed getActivity() which do what I was confused about.
So now everything else is done inside the fragment.